# One-Sample Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test when the values are identical

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank

I'm trying to run One-Sample Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test on my data. My data contains 100 values, and I want to compare these values to a standard value. However, all the 100 values and the standard value are identical. R indicates that the test can't be run as there are no differences. What should I do?

Comment: If all 100 "data" values _exactly_ match the hypothetical median $\eta_0$, are you really curious whether to reject $H_0: \eta = \eta_0?$ What kind of honest data have $0$ variability? In what way is this a statistical question?

Comment: The data is a result of a randomized algorithm. In all the cases the algorithm outputted similar results. It might be that the input is too small and the algorithm was able to find the maximum possible value. I'm required to run the test, but I feel that since there is no variation I can state that the algorithm output similar results.

Comment: Could you to give clarify add a few observations from your sample as part of your question here ? Thx!